# Why applications cannot show their tray icons on the taskbar?

Tags: xubuntu, 18.04, system-tray, taskbar

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04. I do not know what have I done, but all the application tray icons can not show on the taskbar, including input method, uGet, and all applications that have the tray icon feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exactly inside reason of this problem. However I open the Panel Preference GUI window. And I Restore the setting as "Xubuntu Bionic", then the tray icons show properly.

May be the majority of problems of the panel and task bar can be solved by restore to default setting.

Comment: Did you try rebooting first?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I have already shutdown and booted for several times before I need to use ibus frequently.